# Copying arrays with pyCuda from the GPU using pointers

Tags: python, gpu, pycuda

I'm copying via pycuda some arrays on the GPU and then store the pointers to these arrays. How do I recuperate the data back?

`dist = np.zeros(numPoints).astype(np.float32)
distAddress = [gpuarray.to_gpu(dist).ptr for i in range(100)]`

If I call the memcpy_dtoh function:

`buf = np.zeros(400).astype(np.float32)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(buf,distAddress[0])`, (where `type(distAddress[0])` is `long`) I get the following error:

`cuda.memcpy_dtoh(buf, distAddress[0])
LogicError: cuMemcpyDtoH failed: invalid argument`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are using `GPUArrays` the way to copy from device to host is with the `.get()` method. For example

```
dist = np.zeros(num_points).astype(np.float32)
dist_list = [gpuarray.to_gpu(dist) for i in range(100)]

buf = dist_list[0].get()
```